# When is it appropriate to count outcomes to solve a combinatorial probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been looking at problems on this site such as selecting cards from a deck of cards or marbles from a bag of marbles. One thing I have been struggling with is when I can solve the problem simply by counting outcomes, or, equivalently, when I can assume that outcomes have equal probability. I have two recent, motivating examples.

1. [Probability of 2 Cards being adjacent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456347/probability-of-2-cards-being-adjacent/456431#456431). The problem here is to do with the probability of picking cards and finding a seven next to a king. In theory we can solve the problem by considering of 3 groups with identical items in each group: 4 sevens, 4 kings, and 44 others. We then count the number of outcomes of interest, and divide by the total number of outcomes (the total is given by the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)).
2. [probability of occcuring alternative colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457066/probability-of-occcuring-alternative-colors). Here there is one bag, with $n_1$ balls of one color and $n_2$ balls of another, $n_1 \neq n_2$, and we are interested in the probabilities of outcomes when we draw $k < n_1 + n_2$ balls from the bag (with replacement). This is a case where the probabilities of outcomes are not equal.

To quote from the [answer to the second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/457073/77151)

> counting outcomes is not a good way to approach this problem.

I can see in each case, and other cases, when counting is ok -- when outcomes are equally probable, using *common sense* and *intuition*. But this took me quite a long time in the first case. It is also error-prone. It seems like more skilled mathematicians understand when counting is a good way to approach a problem, so my question is:-

**Are there any rules or principles that I can apply to decide whether or not counting outcomes is reasonable?**

(related, more general, question about how to approach combinatorial problems: [Combinatorics: When To Use Different Counting Techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229316/combinatorics-when-to-use-different-counting-techniques))

Comment: In the problem 2 that you mention, there is only one bag. The problem can be perfectly well solved by counting how many of the $7^4$ equally likely possibilities satisfy the alternating colour criterion. The details are essentially the same as the ones we get when we use the "probabilistic" approach. That said, I  prefer direct calculation of probabilities. For one thing it is more general, with equal ease it can deal with fair dice and loaded dice.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks I have fixed the error in my question. Re counting $7^4$ equally likely possibilities, I suppose the key point is that _some of these equally likely possibilities refer to the same outcome_ (this is related to multiplying by $^n\rm{C}_x$ to get binomial probabilities for an outcome -- I was wondering whether that fitted in). That helps, thanks.

Comment: For $7^4$ we need to treat the balls as having Student Numbers. To count the alternating strings count the WBWB and BWBW. Let us count the WBWB. First slot can be filled in $4$ ways, for each the second can be filled in $3$, and so on. Or else the two W slots can be filled in $4^2$ ways and for each the two B slots can be filled in $3^2$ ways.